# Compare each value of one RDD to each key/value pair of another RDD

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

This has been bothering me for a while and I am sure I am being very brainless.

I have two RDDs of key/value pairs, corresponding to a name and associated sparse vector:

```
RDDA = [ (nameA1, sparsevectorA1), (nameA2, sparsevectorA2), (nameA3, sparsevectorA3) ]

RDDB = [ (nameB1, sparsevectorB1), (nameB2, sparsevectorB2) ]
```

I want the end result to compare each element of the first RDD against each element in the second, producing an RDD of 3 * 2 = 6 elements. In particular, I want the name of the element in the second RDD and the dot product of the two sparsevectors:

```
RDDC = [ (nameB1, sparsevectorA1.dot(sparsevectorB1)), (nameB2, sparsevectorA1.dot(sparsevectorB2)), 
(nameB1, sparsevectorA2.dot(sparsevectorB1)), (nameB2, sparsevectorA2.dot(sparsevectorB2)), 
(nameB1, sparsevectorA3.dot(sparsevectorB1)), (nameB2, sparsevectorA3.dot(sparsevectorB2)) ]
```

Is there an appropriate map or inbuilt function to do this?

I assume such an operation must exist hence my feeling of brainlessness. I can easily and inelegantly do this if I collect the two RDDs and then implement a for loop, but of course that is not satisfactory as I want to keep them in RDD form.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an appropriate map or inbuilt function to do this?

Yes, there is and it is called `cartesian`.

```
def transform(ab):
    (_, vec_a), (name_b, vec_b) = ab
    return name_b, vec_a.dot(vec_b)

rddA.cartesian(rddB).map(transform)
```

Problem is that Cartesian product on the large dataset is usually a really bad idea and there is usually much better approach out there.

Comment: Great, that looks like what I was asking for, thanks! Do you have an example of a 'better approach'? I would be very interested to see how the professionals go about these problems.

Comment: Without the context it is hard to tell. If you work with sparse vectors good place to start is reduce the problem to explicit join where you compare only elements which share at least one non-zero position. `flatMap` -> `join` -> `distinct` -> compare. There can be some smarter domain specific solutions (spatial partitioning + `mapPartitions` or modified LSH for example).